# Javascript “addEventListener” function triggered auto when page loaded

Tags: javascript, function, onclicklistener, addeventlistener

This is my code:

```
    const start = document.querySelector('#start');

function AnimationCaller(elParam, name, duration, count, fillMode){
    const element = document.querySelector(elParam);
    element.style.animationName  = name;
    element.style.animationDuration  = duration;
    element.style.animationIterationCount = count;
    element.style.animationFillMode= fillMode;
}

AnimationCaller('.circle-1', 'bounce', '3s', 'infinite');
AnimationCaller('.right-back-foo', 'scale', '6s', 'infinite');

start.addEventListener('click', AnimationCaller('.landing-page', 'slide', '2s', null, 'forwards'))
```

I want the "AnimationCaller" function to run when I click on the "start" object. However, when the page is loaded, "AnimationCaller" works automatically. What is the reason for this and how can I fix it?

Comment: You need to wrap the call to your function in another function.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Please first ***>>>[Search for related topics on SO](https://www.google.com/search?q=eventlistener+too+soon+OR+early+site:stackoverflow.com)<<<***

Answer (score 0):

Change this line

```js
start.addEventListener('click', () => AnimationCaller('.landing-page', 'slide', '2s', null, 'forwards'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you call the function instead of passing a reference to it. Should be fixable by wrapping.

```
start.addEventListener('click', 
    function() { 
         AnimationCaller('.landing-page', 'slide', '2s', null, 'forwards')
    })
```